# UIView not displaying on storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xcode6, xcode-storyboard

I've created a UIView(KGCalloutView) and placed it in my Storyboard(Main.storyboard)by dragging on a View object and setting the class to KGCalloutView. When I run the project however the view is never displayed in the storyboard.

My first attempt to resolve entailed adding the following method, however it resulted in I believe an infinite loop(understandably) and eventually crashed.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    if ([[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KGCalloutView" owner:self options:nil]) {
        [self.view setFrame:[self bounds]];
        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }
}
```

Next I tried adding the init method below, but did not resolve the issue either:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
    }

    return self;
}
```

I tried to post images of my .xib and Main.storyboard but I guess my reputation isn't high enough yet.

Here is KGCalloutView.h:

```
@interface KGCalloutView : UIView <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable NSString *title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet KGCalloutView *view;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *titleField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *typePickerView;

@end
```

Here is KGCalloutView.m:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    if ([[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KGCalloutView" owner:self options:nil]) {
        [self.view setFrame:[self bounds]];
        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }
}

-(void)layoutSubviews{
    self.titleField.text = @"test";
    self.typePickerView.dataSource = self;
    self.typePickerView.delegate = self;
}
```

Here's my ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet KGCalloutView *callout;

@end
```

Here's my ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get a working answer so I just did my nib loading in the ViewController instead of my custom view :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to load view in ViewController to be able to see it.

First, make sure set your view's File's Owner Class to ViewController (looks like you have done this)

[image: file owner]

Second, connect view to property of ViewController (callout)

Third, instead of implementing in KGCalloutView.m, do as following code in ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KGCalloutView" owner:self options:nil]) {
//This will load view from storyboard to IBOutlet callout
        [self.callout setFrame:[self.view bounds]];
        [self.view addSubview:self.callout];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shali. The thing is I don't want to load the view in the view controller. I want to be able to add the view to the view controller in Interface Builder so that I can add my constraints. I know I can add constraints programmatically but I'd much rather not have to.

Comment: Also, my File Owner for my view KGCalloutView.xib is KGCalloutView which is a subclass of UIView, not UIViewController, in case that was unclear.

Comment: For your second item, I do have a property on the View Controller that is tied to the KGCalloutView object on the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Put the nib loading code under initwithcoder

Comment: This causes the initWithCoder to be called. I can put some logic in to only execute it the first time but should this be necessary?

Comment: Take what you have under awakeFromNib and place it under initWithCoder directly before the return.